# UK citizenship and residency requirements

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, eu-citizens, residency

I have a friend who is an EU citizen who lived and worked in UK since 2014.

She got her **settled status document** last year but, sadly, didn't apply immediately for UK citizenship as soon as she was allowed (5+1 year rule).

She had to **leave UK for more than 90 days** during this summer, returning to her EU country to assist relatives during COVID. Thereby, now she lost one requirement to apply [as from here](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain)

> You should not have:
>
> ```
> spent more than 450 days outside the UK during the 5 years before your application
> spent more than 90 days outside the UK in the last 12 months
> ```

Now she's wondering what to do. She's not interested in ethical implications, but only in practical ones.

Should she wait another 12 months, submit without mentioning the break, submit and ask for an exception?
Or consider any other option?

She has a job in UK, has been working remotely since the first lockdown, and continued paying the council tax throughout.

Thanks.

PS: note that this question is not about possible clashes with other citizenships she might have.

PPS: the urgency is given by the fact that she is on a fixed-term contract and doesn't know where she will be in one year.

Comment: Can't she just stay continuously in the UK for another 12 months? At that point she will not have spent more than 90 days outside the UK in the last 12 months.

Comment: Sure she wants to get citizenship? What will happen to her previous citizenship, she might lose that.

Comment: It really depends on what country she's coming from, in terms of what affect gaining British Citizenship will have on her previous citizenship (i.e. some countries do not allow dual-citizenship, and therefore you lose home citizenship when gaining another; Germany requires citizens to get a waiver to maintain citizenship)

Comment: The simplest option is to wait for twelve months since it doesn't require lying or asking for an exception that is probably not possible for the home office to give.  Is there any reason for urgency?  Why doesn't she want to wait?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited to duly clarify.